# @DocumentId on a Non-@Id Field Seems to Make Indexing Invalid for Existing Data in Database

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a class named **Book** that contains 2 fields, **id** and **isbn**.
And I want to perform normal Hibernate queries using the **id** field as the primary key, while perform Hibernate Search queries using the **isbn** field as the primary key.

So I put the **@Id** annotation on the **id** field and the **@DocumentId** annotation on the **isbn** field, as follows.

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @DocumentId(name = "_documentId")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private Long isbn;

    ...
}
```

Then I found that, after the Hibernate Search indexing process starts, although all new updates to the **Book** entities are correctly indexed, the existing **Book** entities in the database are not indexed.

And after I move the **@DocumentId** annotation from the **isbn** field onto the the **id** field as follows, the existing **Book** entities in the database will be indexed again when the Hibernate Search indexing process starts.

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {
    @Id
    @DocumentId(name = "_documentId")
    private Long id;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private Long isbn;

    ...
}
```

So my question is
**Can the Hibernate Search indexing process work same as before, even when the @DocumentId and @Id annotations are on different fields?**.

I use the [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/) to check the Hibernate Search index.

## Libraries

- hibernate-search-orm: **5.5.4.Final**
- hibernate-core: **5.0.3.Final**
- jdk: **1.7.0_79**

## Code

### Entity Class

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @DocumentId(name = "_documentId")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private Long isbn;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private int version;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String content;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(Long isbn, int version, String content) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.version = version;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", isbn=" + isbn + ", version=" + version + ", content=" + content + "]";
    }

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

### Hibernate Mapping File

**Book.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.raychen518.study.hibernate">
    <class name="Book" table="BOOKS">
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="isbn" column="ISBN" />
        <property name="version" column="VERSION" />
        <property name="content" column="CONTENT" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### Hibernate Configuration File

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.lucene_version">LUCENE_CURRENT</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">hibernate.search.test/lucene/indexes</property>

        <mapping resource="Book.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### Application Launcher Class

**BookManager.java**

After executing the **main(String[])** method in the class, the **Book** entity which the **isbn** field is **789** will be created in the index while the existing **Book** entities (*in database*) which the **isbn** fields are **123** and **456** respectively are not indexed.

```
public class BookManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BookManager manager = new BookManager();
        manager.startIndexing();
        manager.saveSome();
    }

    private void startIndexing() throws InterruptedException {
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession());
        fullTextSession.createIndexer(Book.class).startAndWait();
    }

    public void saveSome() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        // session.save(new Book(123L, 1, "abc"));
        // session.save(new Book(456L, 1, "def"));
        session.save(new Book(789L, 1, "ghi"));

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
            return new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many interesting observations, but could you rework it into a question please?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Sanne. Do you mean where the question in the post is (_sorry, my English is not very well_)? If so, my question in the post can be briefed as - **Could the \@DocumentId annotation work same as the \@Id annotation, when the \@DocumentId annotation is on a field different from the one on which the \@Id annotation is?** It seems that when the **@DocumentId** annotation and the **@Id** annotation are on different fields, the Hibernate Search indexing process cannot index the data existing in the database.

Comment: The Hibernate Search indexing process in my above comment means executing the following statement `fullTextSession.createIndexer(Book.class).startAndWait();` in my **BookManager.java** class. After the statement is executed, I checked the Hibernate Search index on the disk by Luke, the newly created Book entity (isbn is 789) is in the index, but those 2 existing Book entities are not.

Comment: @Sanne, I added a question section and library information in original post. Hope it makes the post easier to understand. ^_^ Please feel free to let me know about refining the post or you need more relevant information. Thanks.